# Getting empty bannerId error 204 on integrating Ads for AdMarvel

Tags: php, curl, ads

I am using *adMarvel*. When I make a cUrl request I get an error from adMarvel. I am unable to understand this error as no such *error code (204)* is mentioned in their documantation.
Thanks in advance :)

Params:

```
$url = "http://ads.admarvel.com/fam/postGetAd.php";
$version = "1.5";
$language = "php";
$format = "wap";
$timeout = 5;
$params = site_id=85515&partner_id=eae883d4a30d5b53&timeout=5000&version=1.5&language=php&format=wap&target_params=TYPE%3D%3E2.0&phone_headers=REDIRECT_STATUS%3D%3E200%7C%7CHTTP_HOST%3D%3Ecp.local%7C%7CHTTP_USER_AGENT%3D%3EMozilla%252F5.0%2B%2528Windows%2BNT%2B6.2%253B%2BWOW64%253B%2Brv%253A30.0%2529%2BGecko%252F20100101%2BFirefox%252F30.0%7C%7CHTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE%3D%3Een-gb%252Cen%253Bq%253D0.5%7C%7CHTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING%3D%3Egzip%252C%2Bdeflate%7C%7CPATH%3D%3EC%253A%255CWindows%255Csystem32%253BC%253A%255CWindows%253BC%253A%255CWindows%255CSystem32%255CWbem%253BC%253A%255CWindows%255CSystem32%255CWindowsPowerShell%255Cv1.0%255C%253BC%253A%255CProgram%2BFiles%255CTortoiseSVN%255Cbin%253BC%253A%255CProgram%2BFiles%2B%2528x86%2529%255CMicrosoft%2BSQL%2BServer%255C100%255CTools%255CBinn%255C%253BC%253A%255CProgram%2BFiles%255CMicrosoft%2BSQL%2BServer%255C100%255CTools%255CBinn%255C%253BC%253A%255CProgram%2BFiles%255CMicrosoft%2BSQL%2BServer%255C100%255CDTS%255CBinn%255C%253B%7C%7CSystemRoot%3D%3EC%253A%255CWindows%7C%7CCOMSPEC%3D%3EC%253A%255CWindows%255Csystem32%255Ccmd.exe%7C%7CPATHEXT%3D%3E.COM%253B.EXE%253B.BAT%253B.CMD%253B.VBS%253B.VBE%253B.JS%253B.JSE%253B.WSF%253B.WSH%253B.MSC%7C%7CWINDIR%3D%3EC%253A%255CWindows%7C%7CSERVER_SIGNATURE%3D%3E%7C%7CSERVER_SOFTWARE%3D%3EApache%252F2.4.4%2B%2528Win64%2529%2BOpenSSL%252F1.0.1d%2BPHP%252F5.4.12%7C%7CSERVER_NAME%3D%3Ecp.local%7C%7CSERVER_ADDR%3D%3E127.0.0.1%7C%7CSERVER_PORT%3D%3E80%7C%7CREMOTE_ADDR%3D%3E127.0.0.1%7C%7CDOCUMENT_ROOT%3D%3ED%253A%252Fcourse-project%252Fbeta%252Fpublic%7C%7CREQUEST_SCHEME%3D%3Ehttp%7C%7CCONTEXT_PREFIX%3D%3E%7C%7CCONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT%3D%3ED%253A%252Fcourse-project%252Fbeta%252Fpublic%7C%7CSERVER_ADMIN%3D%3Eadmin%2540example.com%7C%7CSCRIPT_FILENAME%3D%3ED%253A%252Fcourse-project%252Fbeta%252Fpublic%252Findex.php%7C%7CREMOTE_PORT%3D%3E52731%7C%7CREDIRECT_URL%3D%3E%252FAdmarvel%7C%7CGATEWAY_INTERFACE%3D%3ECGI%252F1.1%7C%7CSERVER_PROTOCOL%3D%3EHTTP%252F1.1%7C%7CREQUEST_METHOD%3D%3EGET%7C%7CQUERY_STRING%3D%3E%7C%7CREQUEST_URI%3D%3E%252FAdmarvel%7C%7CSCRIPT_NAME%3D%3E%252Findex.php%7C%7CPHP_SELF%3D%3E%252Findex.php%7C%7CREQUEST_TIME_FLOAT%3D%3E1402557978.064%7C%7CREQUEST_TIME%3D%3E1402557978
```

Request:

```
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeOut);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeOut);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Connection: Close"));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$ad_contents = curl_exec($request);
```

Error:
    HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Admarvel-ErrorCode: 204 Admarvel-ErrorReason: Bannerid empty, banner must not be configured.